# HTTP Status 500 - Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver

Tags: sql-server, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to access MS SQL server 2005 from a servlet file. I am using JDBC 4.0 driver.
I have already added the JAR files `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar` files to my Tomcat `/lib` folder.

But while running code I am getting an error

> HTTP Status 500 - Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

My code is:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn = conn =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=school;user=sa;password=123");
PrintWriter pwOut = res.getWriter();
pwOut.println("Connected");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String searchCriteria = req.getParameter("txtSearch");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from student");
res.setContentType("text/html");
```

Answer (score 24):

The error message is pretty clear. Tomcat is using the wrong driver.

You state that you copied `sqljdbc.jar` **and** `sqljdbc4.jar` into the Tomcat lib folder. That is most probably the reason for your problem.

You **only** need `sqljdbc4.jar` otherwise Tomcat picks up the wrong one.

Try to delete `sqljdbc.jar` from the Tomcat lib folder

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Code to connect java to Microsoft sql Server 2012

You only need sqljdbc4.jar that avail on offical Microsoft website. Here is the link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/A/02AAE597-3865-456C-AE7F-613F99F850A8/sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.exe

It contains 2 jar files, and I am trying to use **sqljdbc4.jar**. This is the code I am using to connect:

```
package com.Sql.ConnectDB;

import java.sql.*;
public class DbClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            **String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Student";**//important
            String user="username";
            String pass="password";
            **Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");**//important
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            System.out.println("Conneccted Successfully");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```